# How do I manage conflicting versions in CocoaPods?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

newby here.

I am having an issue while trying to eject a react native app from Expo.

When I run pod install, I get the following error:

```
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In Podfile:
        EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
          Firebase/Core (= 6.14.0) was resolved to 6.14.0, which depends on
            Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.14.0)
    
        RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 10.4.0, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 7.3.0)
```

Essentially, one module that I am using (the most update to date version of that module) has a dependency with version **6.14.0** of "Firebase/CoreOnly"

Another module I am using, has a dependency with version **7.3.0** of "Firebase/CoreOnly"

How do I "downgrade" the dependency for the second module so that it also points to version 6.14.0?

Or failing that, is there a way that the the project can use two different versions in parallel?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my solution was to completely remove expo-firebase from my project and do all the work with @react-native-firebase. I don't think it is possible to downgrade @react-native-firebase to 6.14.0